# Toast is not showing- emulated with genymotion

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop an android app with android studio 2.3.3 and genymotion 2.10.0
I'm using toast msg to show the firebase connection result but it's not displayed despite there are no errors.
here is my code

```
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed !",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            setContentView(R.layout.failure);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else{
                            setContentView(R.layout.success);
                            Intent settings = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(settings);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: are you able to see `SettingsActivity.class` ?

Comment: There is no problem in Toast syntax. Check whether it is going in if part or else part

Comment: Make sure that if statement is execute or not?

Comment: Have you tried to show it in the main thread? Yeah, and make sure your code is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't show because you finish the Activity after the toast
you can change your ActivityContext to applicationContext

`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`